# Profile settings - VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am very new to VS Code, I'm hoping this will be a simple quick fix!

I have set up two profiles in VS Code, one for Production use - mainly to use Powershell as an intended replacement for ISE

I have a second profile, for Dev and testing, mainly for learning

Each profile uses a separate MS account, linked to different Azure tenants.

When I switch between profiles, the project/workspace/folder from the previous profile is loaded.

For example:

Profile 1 - working directory is D:\ , working on a PS script saved in D:
Switch to Profile 2 - still working in D:\ with same script open

Manually open the correct folder whilst logged into Profile 2 - say E:\

Switch back to Profile 1 - I'm still in E:\

Is this expected behaviour when switching between profiles, and can it be changed?

Thanks in advance

Switched profiles, expected last project I was working on in that profile to open

Comment: I would recomment using `code-insiders` build along with `code` to avoid switching profiles at all

Comment: https://code.visualstudio.com/insiders/

Comment: when you say profiles, do you mean https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/profiles ? If so, then yes, I'm pretty sure this is by-design.